# Dockerization of SpringBoot-Microservice, + Angular + MySQL + RabbitMQ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I'm learning docker. While deploying my application(Angular, SpringBoot, RabbitMQ, MySQL), I'm able to access UI, but services are getting failed due to connection error between services and MySQL and RabbitMq. But individually I'm able to access both MySql and RabbitMq through docker exec command also tables and queues are getting generating while docker-compose up. But while testing, its not working

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.17
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: stackroute
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_USER: cmatches
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: cmatches

  user-app:
    image: userservice
    build: userservice/
    ports:
      - 9100:9100
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    network_mode: "host"

  fav-app:
    image: favouriteservice
    build: favouriteservice/
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - rabbitmq
    network_mode: "host"

  rec-app:
    image: matchrecommendationservice
    build: matchrecommendationservice/
    ports:
      - 9300:9300
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - rabbitmq
    network_mode: "host"

  cmatches-ui:
    build: CMatchesUI/
    container_name: cmatchesUi
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
```

Individual dockerfile is working fine.

Error:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Do I need to change something in application.properties

```
server.port=9200

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stackroute?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&requireSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.recommendedMatchesChannel.destination=recommendedMatches
spring.cloud.stream.default.contentType=application/json
```

=========================================================================
Updates: 
1.
Tried changing 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/stackroute?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&requireSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
Got following error :
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql

-Reverted-

2.
Removed network_mode: host
got following error

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
user-app_1     | 
user-app_1     | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
user-app_1     |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
user-app_1     |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
user-app_1     |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:827) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
user-app_1     |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:447) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
user-app_1     |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:237) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
user-app_1     |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
user-app_1     |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
user-app_1     |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
user-app_1     |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
user-app_1     |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
user-app_1     |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
user-app_1     |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
user-app_1     |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
user-app_1     |    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
user-app_1     |    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
user-app_1     |    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
user-app_1     |    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
user-app_1     |    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
user-app_1     |    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
user-app_1     |    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
user-app_1     |    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
user-app_1     |    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
user-app_1     |    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
user-app_1     |    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
user-app_1     |    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
user-app_1     |    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
user-app_1     |    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
user-app_1     |    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
user-app_1     |    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
user-app_1     |    at com.stackroute.userservice.UserServiceApplication.main(UserServiceApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:1.0]
user-app_1     |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
user-app_1     |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
user-app_1     |    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
user-app_1     |    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[userservice-1.0.jar:1.0]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[userservice-1.0.jar:1.0]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[userservice-1.0.jar:1.0]
user-app_1     |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) ~[userservice-1.0.jar:1.0]
user-app_1     | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
user-app_1     | 
user-app_1     | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
user-app_1     |    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
user-app_1     |    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
user-app_1     |    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
user-app_1     |    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
user-app_1     |    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
user-app_1     |    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
user-app_1     |    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
user-app_1     |    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
user-app_1     |    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
user-app_1     |    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:150) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
user-app_1     |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:947) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
user-app_1     |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:817) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
user-app_1     |    ... 57 common frames omitted
user-app_1     | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
user-app_1     |    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
user-app_1     |    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
user-app_1     |    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
user-app_1     |    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
user-app_1     |    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
user-app_1     |    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
user-app_1     |    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
user-app_1     |    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
user-app_1     |    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

Comment: use jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306

Comment: tried it's showing same error with Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql

Comment: all of localhost should be changhed with the service names from docker-compose file

Comment: @LinPy ok let me try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `localhost` as the host name since the applications are run in a docker container. Also, to communicate each other, all the containers should be in the same docker network;

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    networks:
      - my-net

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.17
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: stackroute
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_USER: cmatches
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: cmatches
    networks:
      - my-net

  user-app:
    image: userservice
    build: userservice/
    container_name: userapp
    ports:
      - 9100:9100
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - my-net

  fav-app:
    image: favouriteservice
    build: favouriteservice/
    container_name: favapp
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - rabbitmq
    networks:
      - my-net

  rec-app:
    image: matchrecommendationservice
    build: matchrecommendationservice/
    container_name: recapp
    ports:
      - 9300:9300
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - rabbitmq
    networks:
      - my-net

  cmatches-ui:
    build: CMatchesUI/
    container_name: cmatchesUi
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
    networks:
      - my-net

networks:
    my-net:
```

Replace host name in all places to their respective container names like this;

```
server.port=9200

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/stackroute?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&requireSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.rabbitmq.host=rabbitmq
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.recommendedMatchesChannel.destination=recommendedMatches
spring.cloud.stream.default.contentType=application/json
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working fine now. Is it required to give networks?

Comment: Check this out. You could have some insight ► https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/#the-default-bridge-network

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you use `network_mode = host`

This means that you would like to "reuse" the namespace from the underlying host network.

Try to use the default "bridge" mode so that docker will create a "virtual network" between the containers.

This bridge mode is the default one, so just remove the line `network_mode: "host"` from the docker compose file.

[Here](https://www.nuagenetworks.net/blog/docker-networking-overview/) is one nice tutorial that descibes docker network support at the high level.